# JavaScript/jQuery working with Date and Time Objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement a simple "seconds" counter.

Want to do something like this:

```
var start = new Date();
var sectionEnd = new Date();

var startTime = start.getTime();
var sectionEndTime = sectionEnd.getTime();

$('#next').on('click', function()){
  // set start time if NOT set or use set startTime
  $('#start-time').text().length < 1 ? startTime : $(this).text();

  // set or update section end time
  $('#section-end-time').html(sectionEndTime)

  // calculate the difference from startTime to current sectionEndTime
  var elapsedTime = startTime - sectionEndTime;

  // alert elapsed time in seconds..
  alert(elapsedTime);
}
```

So obviously the above is pseudo code and I just wrote to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. Is there a simple jQuery solution to this? Perhaps 3-4 lines of code without using an external plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$.now()`, like that:

HTML:

```
<button id="startDate">Date</button>
<p></p>
```

Jquery:

```
 $("#startDate").on("click",function()
 {
  DateDifference();
 });

 function DateDifference()
 {
    var date1 = new Date($.now());
    setInterval(function()
    {
      var date2 = new Date($.now());
      var seconds = (date2 - date1)/1000;
      $("p").html(seconds+" seconds of differrence between date1 and date2");
    }, 1000);
 }
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/56ojwos5/